# Custom Solr Full Import

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

I have a solr core core1, which has a couple of Facet Types and I want to implement a custom Import for them. 
For eg:
I have the Following Facet Types:

- Facet1
- Facet2
- Facet3

When I use the Data Import Handler, I don't want to do the "delta" for business reasons, and I just want to do a clean / Full-Import for Facet1 and Facet2 and leave alone Facet3. Is this possible in Solr?

Any help / direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an approach similar to the one mentioned at 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerDeltaQueryViaFullImport.

Your query in data-config.xml will then be

```
<entity ...
    query="SELECT ... 
             WHERE '${dataimporter.request.clean}' = 'true'
                    OR 
                   facet IN (facet1, facet2)">
```

So for indexing documents only in `facet1` and `facet2` you would use

`dataimport?command=full-import&clean=false`

For doing a full import for all facets, use:

`dataimport?command=full-import&clean=true`

(I haven't tested this, so just make sure.)